# How to exclude value without excluding blanks?

Tags: ldap

In LDAP excluding a certain attribute value also automatically excludes blank values. What is the best way to write an LDAP query to exclude an attribute value without excluding blank values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following search filter:

(|(!(attribute=value))(!(attribute=*)))

It excludes objects with attribute=value without excluding objects with a blank value of this attribute.

Comment: Technically, the query excludes entries with no value vs those with a blank value.

Comment: @jwilleke That would depend on which directory you aren't querying. I know in Active Directory, there is no such thing as blank values (if you try to set something to a blank value, the effect is that the value is removed). I don't know about OpenLDAP...

Comment: @jwilleke In which implementation of LDAP no value is different from a blank value? I doubt this difference is compliant with the LDAP specifications.

Comment: Nothing to do with any specific LDAP implementation, some folks literally have attribute values with a " " (blank string) and even an attribute values that contains a NULLs.

Comment: @jwilleke In my answer by “blank value” I mean the absence of value, not a value defined as space (ASCII 32) or null (ASCII 0) or any other character like tab, new line, return, etc.